# Get Nested Output Dynamically in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I want to build an expression in ADF via concatenation, then evaluate the nested expression.

Basically, I have a Web Activity which is returning json output.  I need to access an element of the output that has multiple possible keys, and can be nested at multiple levels.  I want to use pipeline parameters to access my desired element regardless of the key or level it resides at.

Here is a sample input:

```
{
"status": "OK",
"code": 200,
"timestamp": "2020-11-02T15:22:59Z",
"messages": [],
"result": {}
"paging" : {"total_count" : 1000}
}
```

I can grab the desired output statically like this:

```
@{activity('callAPI').output['paging']['total_count']}
```

I can also generate the above expression dynamically like this:

```
@{concat('activity(''callAPI'').output', pipeline().parameters.myPipelineParam)}
```

However, once I create the expression via concatenation, I can't figure out how to also evaluate it in the same expression.

Any ideas on how to do this, or perhaps a better method I'm not seeing?

Comment: did you try `json` expression? what the output look like?

Comment: the activity output is already formatted as json.  i added some sample output above

Comment: When using the output in expression, it's a string.